# problemas al indexar sobre un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indices

Estoy trabajando con un archivo csv en pandas al buscar las columnas sobre las que quiero trabajar me da un key error sin embargo ese nombre si existe,por ello he pensado utilizar el indice de la columna,pero me da un error al intentar esto
`df[[1,4,7,9,10,14,15]]`

Answer (score 1):

Si te lanza un `KeyError` al indizar con un nombre de columna con `df["nombre"]` o una lista de ellos con `df[["nombre1", "nombre2"]]` es que un nombre no es correcto y no existe. Algo tienes mal en el nombre que usas para indizar (mayúsculas-minúsculas, algún espacio que no agregas, etc). Haz un `print(df.columns)` y mira los nombres de las columnas para asegurarte.

Dicho ésto, para indizar usando índices numéricos usa `pandas.DataFrame.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:, [1, 4, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15]]
```

recuerda que el indizado es base cero.